# Return results from mySQL even if the user does not fill all the criteria in form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following code needs to make use of 3 variables given by the user. By default all of these variables equal to 0.

1. time (textbox)
2. city (drop down list)
3. type (drop down list)

If for example time and city is given by the user, but lets the type zero, it will not return any results. 
My question is what is an effective and efficient way to modify my existing code so that if the user chooses not to select time, city or type or any combination of these, there will be results returned?

For example if *time* 21:00 is added with *city* number 3, it will show all the *types* that meet the 2 criteria should be listed.

```
$question= 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `time`, :time )) < 2 AND city=:city AND type=:type';
$query = $db->prepare($question);
$query->bindValue(":time", $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(":city", $city, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$question= 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE ';

$hasTime = false;
if(!empty($time)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasTime = true;
    $question .= 'ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `time`, :time )) < 2 ';
}

$hasCity = false;
if(!empty($city)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasCity = true;
    $question .= 'AND city=:city ';
}

$hasType = false;
if(!empty($type)) { // @note better validation here
    $hasType = true;
    $question .= 'AND type=:type';
}

$query = $db->prepare($question);

if($hasTime)
    $query->bindValue(":time", $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($hasCity)
    $query->bindValue(":city", $city, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($hasType)
    $query->bindValue(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();

if(empty($results))
    echo 'no results';
else
    // $results is an array of arrays
```

Comment: Noticed I'd forgotten to default `$hasType = false;` earlier; now revised.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Can you please let me know, how to show a "no results" message when no rows are found by the query ?

Comment: sure, i threw it in at the bottom, how about an up vote on top of the accepted answer, haha :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using an array of conditions, and checking through to see if the conditions exist, to built the individual parts of the SQL query:

```
$conditions = array(); // Creating an array of conditions.
if ($time) // Checks to see if value exists.
{
    $timeCondition = "ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `time`, :time )) < 2";
    $conditions[] = $timeCondition; // Adds this condition string to the array.
}
if ($city)
{
    $cityCondition = "city=:city";
    $conditions[] = $cityCondition;
}
if ($type)
{
    $typeCondition = "type=:type";
    $conditions[] = $typeCondition;
}

$conditionString = implode(" AND ", $conditions); // Gluing the values of the array with " AND " in between the string conditions.

if (count($conditions) > 0) // If conditions exist, add "WHERE " to the condition string.
{
    $conditionString = "WHERE ".$conditionString;
}
else // Otherwise, the condition string is blank by default.
{
    $conditionString = '';
}

$question= 'SELECT * FROM events '.$conditionString; // If no conditions, will return all from events. Otherwise, conditions will be slotted in through $conditionString.

$query = $db->prepare($question);

if($time)
    $query->bindValue(":time", $time, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($city)
    $query->bindValue(":city", $city, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($type)
    $query->bindValue(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: It seems that this is the same with Truth answer, I checked it and it doesnot work..

Comment: @Kaoukkos Yes, that's because Truth copied my answer and modified it without thinking about whether or not it would work :) I've just edited it to do a check on the variables before binding. You can give this another try.

Comment: @Kaoukkos More importantly, don't just grab an answer and copy and paste into your code and assume on first glance "it works." Try different test cases, and make sure you understand the description of the logic behind the code. Make sure to read the comments in my code and try to understand what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Build the query dynamically so that if the field is at its default, do not include it in the where clause.

```
$conditions = array();
if ($_POST['time']) {
    $conditions[] = "ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `time`, :time )) < 2";
}
if ($_POST['city']) {
    $conditions[] = "city=:city";
}
if ($_POST['type']) {
    $conditions[] = "type=:type";
}

$conditionString = implode(" AND ", $conditions);
if (count($conditions) > 0) {
    $conditionString = "WHERE " . $conditionString;
}
else {
    $conditionString = '';
}
$question = 'SELECT * FROM events ' . $conditionString;
```

Comment: This solution looks pretty good but it doesn't seem to work I have tested quickshiftin answer and it works...

Comment: Also sounded like _time_ is supposed to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of `IF()` statements in your SQL statement, and return true if the value isn't set. So something like this:

```
...WHERE IF(:time, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `time`, :time)) < 2, 1)
AND IF(:city, city=:city, 1) AND IF(:type, type=:type, 1)
```